# iPad iOS Safari getUserMedia acces specific camera ( front or back )

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, getusermedia

What is the right way to access the the front or back camera.

Currently I'm only able to access the "user" camera ( front ).

I can't switch to back camera using any constraints.

Using a specific device id is also not working:

```
var constraints = {
    video: {
        facingMode: "environment",
        deviceId: "E858F78F6026428D45DD669617B4A881409AA4DA"
    }
};

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
```

Cany somebody please help me?

It is always accessing the front camera.

Comment: Please follow the [question guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following your question I think you already have successfully called `getUserMedia()` to get the user's permission to access the camera (otherwise you won't have get the front camera to work). This is needed because the `label` values in the following JSON will only be filled when the user has already granted access.

On iOS you now have to call `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` and will get a "response JSON" like that:

```
[
  {  
    "deviceId":"<firstID>",
    "kind":"audioinput",
    "label":"iPhone Microphone",
    "groupId":""
  },
  {  
    "deviceId":"<secondID>",
    "kind":"videoinput",
    "label":"Back Camera",
    "groupId":""
  },
  {  
    "deviceId":"<thirdID>",
    "kind":"videoinput",
    "label":"Front Camera",
    "groupId":""
  }
]
```

using the `deviceId` of the device you want or let the user choose it using a basic UI will give you access to the back camera.

**Caution:** The `deviceId` values will change on each invocation of `enumerateDevices()`!

Comment: I tried to alert the device label, it is actually empty, and there is only one device too. I am testing an iPhone X, which has front and back cameras.

Comment: @RainCast you need to call it after `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` returns success

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass this in as an argument when you are calling getUserMedia.

```
video: {
    facingMode: {
        exact: 'environment'
    }
}
```

This will return the back camera's video:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: {
        facingMode: {
            exact: 'environment'
        }
    }
})
```